# Capture image (from background) when screen is locked

Tags: expo, react-native-camera

I'm trying to implement a functionality to capture image through front camera when someone tries to unlock my device a number of times. I believe it's possible on Android and some existing Android apps already do this. I'm not sure if it's possible on iOS, however. Does anyone know if captures can be made when the screen is off and locked using expo or RNCamera though? I can't seem to even get the camera to make a capture while the app is away from the foreground on Android.

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution? Help will be much appreciated. Thanks, I'm fine even if the solution is for android.

Comment: @Ezekiel I'm afraid not. :(

Comment: wow , So one might need to write custom module and hope it even works. I will try seeing if I can test it, even tho the view will pop up, I know people say it will crash, but there's no harm in trying.